# How do you poll data from a device in C++ without blocking?

Tags: c++, polling

I have a device connected via USB, which is outputting a stream of characters separated by a newline, every few seconds. I want to repeatedly poll this device for input without blocking on the event that no such input exists.

I am trying to use the `poll()` function as recommended on other questions, however, it is not working, and I am having trouble determining where I am going wrong.

My device is at `/dev/TTYACM0` and when I run `cat /dev/TTYACM)` I can see the stream of data.

This is my current program, however it just causes a segmentation fault:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){
    char buf[1024];
    int fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    int ret;
    if (fd < 0){
        std::cout << "ERROR" << fd << std::endl;
    }

    int i;

    struct pollfd *pfds;

    while(1){
        pfds->fd = 0;
        pfds->events = POLLIN;
        ret = poll(pfds, 1, 0);
        if (ret > 0) {
            if (pfds->revents & POLLWRBAND)
            {
                i = read(0, buf, 1024);
                if (!i){
                    printf("stdin closed\n");
                    return 0;
                }
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

UPDATE:

I fixed the code, here is the working version

```
#include <poll.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(){

    char readBuf[5];
    char c;
    std::string buf;
    int counter = 0;
    int ret;
    int i;

    struct pollfd mypoll;
    int fd = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);

    //init mypoll
    memset(&mypoll, 0, sizeof(mypoll));
    mypoll.fd = fd;
    mypoll.events = POLLIN;

    while(1){
        // poll (pointer to pollfd, number of polls, timeout)
        // noneg = successful poll
        // 0 = systemcall timeout (no data)
        // -1, errno set to indicate error
        ret = poll(&mypoll, 1, 0);
        if (ret == 1){
            int bytes_read = read(fd, readBuf, sizeof(readBuf));
            for (i = 0; readBuf[i] != '\n' && i < bytes_read; i++){
                buf.push_back(readBuf[i]);
            }
            std::cout << "#" << buf << "#" << std::endl;
            buf = "";   
        }
    }

    printf("done\n");

    close(fd);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself, what happens here`pfds->fd` on the very first iteration?

Comment: I really don't know, I was just trying to emulate the only example of this I could find https://linuxhint.com/use-poll-system-call-c/

Comment: Aahh I see, so that should be the valid fd not 0. I bit confused why the example does this

Comment: Okay after doing some reading I now see the example code was trying to read from fd 0 which is std in and write to stdout. That makes more sense. Still curious what the best way to achieve this for reading data from a file would be

Comment: @user19802847 There is a more basic mistake in the code. You never initialize `pfds`, so the very first `pfds->fd` is trying to dereference an uninitialized pointer, causing undefined behavior. There is an example for using `poll` on its man page, see https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html. (Although that is written in C and needs some minor adjustments for C++.)

Comment: Updated the code with the now working code. Thanks for the help all

Comment: You should put the working code as an answer (not add it to the question).